# Include runtime dependencies in karaf:features-generate-descriptor

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf, sesame, karaf

I have an OSGi project that includes the sesame-runtime-osgi dependency with a compile scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
    <artifactId>sesame-runtime-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>${sesame.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The sesame-runtime-osgi artifact includes several runtime dependencies. For example:

```
+- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-runtime-osgi:jar:2.7.13:compile
|  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-http-client:jar:2.7.13:compile
|  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-http-protocol:jar:2.7.13:compile
|  |  |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-ntriples:jar:2.7.6:compile
|  |  |     \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
|  |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-query:jar:2.7.13:compile
.
.
.
|  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:runtime
|  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-http-server-spring:jar:2.7.13:compile
|     +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-runtime:jar:2.7.6:compile
|     |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-repository-manager:jar:2.7.13:compile
.
.
.
|     |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryresultio-sparqljson:jar:2.7.13:runtime
|     |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:runtime
|     |  +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-queryresultio-text:jar:2.7.13:runtime
|     |  |  \- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.0:runtime
.
.
.
|     \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
|        \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
```

You'll notice that "net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.0" is a runtime dependency so it is not included in the feature.xml generated by the karaf-maven-plugin. Unfortunately the package needed at runtime **is** included in the "Import-Packages" directive in the sesame-runtime-osgi Manifest:

```
Import-Package: au.com.bytecode.opencsv
```

so Karaf cannot deploy the feature unless I manually wrap and deploy the runtime dependencies myself. Obviously I don't want to have to do that.

Is there a way I can include dependencies with runtime scope in the feature.xml generation?

Thanks

Comment: as you don't say which version of Karaf maven plugins you're using, did you a) try with 3.0.2, b) the latest snapshot and c) usually it's best to ask at the mailinglist for karaf.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this with 3.0.2 and 4.0.0.M1. Something similar occurs with the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), but it is fixed by using a ServicesResourceTransformer. I just sent a message to the user list. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating your features.xml using the standard Karaf mojo then you can create a features template file in src/main/features/features.xml
Whatever you put in that template will appear in your final generated features.xml
So if absolutely necessary you can hard code the runtime dependencies in the template.

You could specify each transitive dependency manually in the pom. That would also work presumably?

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on Richard's answer, the template file should be located in

```
src/main/feature/feature.xml
```

NOT

```
src/main/features/features.xml
```

Inside the feature.xml template file you can include dependency bundles and features that will be merged with the generated ones.  For example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}">
  <feature name="${project.artifactId}" description="${project.name}" version="${project.version}">
    <bundle>mvn:net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/2.0</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```